# Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)

Tags: android, eclipse, layout-inflater

I think that the program keeps crashing because of this

```
public class ViewAll extends Activity {
    TableLayout t;
    MyDBManager d;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);
        t = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
        d = new MyDBManager(ViewAll.this);
        Inflated();
    }

    private void Inflated()
    {
        Item[] items = d.GetAllItemsArray();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row;
        Button buttonInfo;
        TextView priceInfo;
        TextView itemInfo;
        for (int i=0;i<items.length; i++)
        {
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.onetask, null); //Here lies the problem
            itemInfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            priceInfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            itemInfo.setText(items[i].getName());
            priceInfo.setText(items[i].getPrice());
            buttonInfo = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttonInfo.setTag(items[i].getId() + "");
            buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(l);
            t.addView(row);
        }
    }

    OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewAll.this, v.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(ViewAll.this, UpdateItems.class);
            i.putExtra("itemid", v.getTag().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {enter code here
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_all, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not crash.

The worse you can get is an incorrect layout display. However the warning is true about avoiding to send null as parent. You should pass always the root view (there are exceptions). And if you pass the root view you must also pass a boolean as the 3rd parameter. That boolean means either you want to inject the inflated view on the root you just passed or not. So if you pass true your parent view will have the inflated view inside it.